# UILabel appears with border by default in ios 7.1

Tags: ios, ios7.1

`UILabel` appears with border by default only in iOS 7.1 even there is no border set.

Is there any ios 7.1 bug or any mistake?

Comment: It is not possible .. please put your label's image with code or write yourUILabel.clipsToBounds = YES OR yourUILabel.layer.masksToBounds = YES; ;

Comment: can you provide a screenshot and the code, because I don't see any such thing in my apps.

Answer (score 0):

Double check if you're not setting the appearance of the label globally using the `UIApperance` protocol. Default appearance of a `UILabel` on iOS is without any border. If the border appears, then you must be calling `label.layer.borderWidth`.

In short. Do a text search for:

1. `.layer.borderWidth`
2. `[UILabel appearance]`

and check if you are setting it somewhere in your code.